# Why the tint color is applied to other icons?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-toolbar, material-components-android

Consider this simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"
                app:navigationIconTint="@color/red"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"
                android:text="@string/my_string"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And have 2 problems:

1. navigationIcon and navigationIconTint don't work. The toolbar keeps the default icon, with the default back button and default color.
2. This is quite weird: since the `MaterialTextView` in the `android:drawableEnd` uses the same icon as the Toolbar (ic_arrow_left), it gets the color red. It seems like the same icon used in the toolbar is then applied to the TextView even if here no tint is specified. It seems a bug to me.

NOTE: About the 1 I should mention that I am using navigation component and the back icon is automatically generated by the Nav Componnt itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Navigation components you can use the **`addOnDestinationChangedListener`** to set your custom icon and tint:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    if (destination.id == R.id.xxx){
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx)
        toolbar.setNavigationIconTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.xxx))

    }
}
```

Comment: I have set my toolbar in one of the nested fragments how do I get an instance of the toolbar in navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener in the MainActivity?